# Patching Google Event start-date and end-date without having all necessary data

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm implementing the client that can **patch** Google Calendar Event via [Calendar API v3 Client Library for Java.](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/calendar/v3)

method:

```
com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Events#patch
```

The problem that I faced is that `start` and `end` fields in `com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event` entity are complex objects and require several things to be constructed:

1. `com.google.api.client.util.DateTime`
2. `TimeZone`

DateTime has fields called `dateOnly` that is set to true/false depending on whether the event is all day event or not. Here the problem comes. If I want to update only the date, and only the date is sent from my Front-End(without the flag whether it is all day event or `dateOnly` is applicable), I can't construct `DateTime` object because I don't know whether I should use constructor of `DateTime` with `dateOnly` set to true or set to false.

In terms if request, it's correct. Since we have PATCH, we can update particular fields without even touching the rest. However, in this case, since the field is rather complex, it's rather difficult to find the way no to update `dateOnly` flag, but to `update` value or `tzShift`.

I consider loading event from Google every time I do patch. Thus, I can read and set `dateOnly` flag to the old value. Is there a more convenient way to address the issue?

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation in [Events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events) there is no **dateOnly** resource found.
but you can use below options using patch [Events: patch](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch)

```
{
    "start": {
       "date": "2017-05-05",
       "dateTime": "",
       "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
    },
    "end": {
       "date": "2017-05-06",
       "dateTime": "",
       "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
    }
}
```

Hope it may help you.